# Is there any possibility to generate random numbers using XQuery?

Tags: xquery

I have to generate a series of random numbers using XQuery.I found a set of libraries but those are paid.If anyone can give me a direction it would be much appreciated(preferably code).

Comment: please read [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)..your question can be answered over [google](http://www.google.com)..

Comment: If you can use XSLT, the FXSL library (written in pure XSLT) provides several templates/functions for generating random sequences of givem length. More about this here: http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/articles/Random/Casting%20the%20Dice%20with%20FXSL-htm.htm

Comment: The question should be reopen. It asks how to implement algorithm that generates pseudo-random number using XQuery language without any extra libraries. For example how to implement Linear Congruential algorithm to generate random numbers with XQUery language

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard XQuery languages provides no random function, but many implementations do. Some examples for open source implementations:

- BaseX provides a [Random Module](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Random_Module)
- Zorba has a [Random Module](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/modules/zorba/xdm/atomic/random), too
- eXist-db has some suitable functions in the [Util Module](http://demo.exist-db.org:8098/exist/functions/util)
- MarkLogic provides the [xdmp:random()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:random) function

As an alternative, most Java implementations of XQuery (such as BaseX, Saxon or Qizx) provide so-called *Java bindings* in order to evaluate Java code:

```
declare namespace math = 'java:java.lang.Math';
math:random()
```

If the implementation support the latest XQuery 3.0 specification, this can also be written as a one-liner:

```
Q{java:java.lang.Math}random()
```

Comment: To add to your list: MarkLogic -- xdmp:random()

Comment: A little update: In the Functions & Operators specification of XQuery 3,1 the function fn:random-number-generator was introduced (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-random-number-generator or http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_3.1#fn:random-number-generator).

Comment: As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30099090/3534491), since Saxon 9.2 this solution only works with the commercial editions. However, Saxon 9.2 introduced another mechanism, [Integrated extension functions](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/extensibility/integratedfunctions/index.html), which is available in all editions.